# Compute $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{ \sqrt[3]{1+\sin x} - \sqrt[3]{1- \sin x }}{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals, limits-without-lhopital

> Compute $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \dfrac{ \sqrt[3]{1+\sin x} - \sqrt[3]{1- \sin x }}{x}$

Original question was to solve $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \dfrac{ \sqrt[3]{1+ x } - \sqrt[3]{1-x }}{x}$ and it was solved by adding and subtracting 1 in denominator.  Making it in the form $\lim\limits_{x \to a}\dfrac {x^n - a^n}{x-a} = ax^{n-1}$

How to solve for above limit without using lhopitals rule?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**.  Use
$$u-v=\frac{u^3-v^3}{u^2+uv+v^2}$$
with
$$u=(1+\sin x)^{1/3}\ ,\quad v=(1-\sin x)^{1/3}\ .$$
You should know
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x$$
without appealing to l'Hopital's Rule.

Comment: $\frac23$ realy.

Comment: I got ! Thanks :) I unconsciously cancelled one $1$ in denominator :P

Answer (score 3):

*Just another way using Taylor series.*

$$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+O\left(x^4\right)$$ Now, using the generalized binomial theorem 
$$\sqrt[3]{1+\sin(x)}=1+\frac{x}{3}-\frac{x^2}{9}+\frac{x^3}{162}+O\left(x^4\right)$$
$$\sqrt[3]{1-\sin(x)}=1-\frac{x}{3}-\frac{x^2}{9}-\frac{x^3}{162}+O\left(x^4\right)$$
Using the above,
$$\sqrt[3]{1+\sin(x)}-\sqrt[3]{1-\sin(x)}=\frac{2 x}{3}+\frac{x^3}{81}+O\left(x^4\right)$$
$$\dfrac{ \sqrt[3]{1+\sin (x)} - \sqrt[3]{1- \sin (x) }}{x}=\frac{2}{3}+\frac{x^2}{81}+O\left(x^3\right)$$ which shows the limit and also how it is approached.

Making the problem more general considering 
$$A=\frac{(1+\sin (x))^k-(1-\sin (x))^k}{x}$$ and using the same process, we should obtain
$$A=2k+\frac{k \left(k^2-3 k+1\right)}{3} x^2+O\left(x^3\right)$$

Comment: Expansion at order $1$ would be enough.

Comment: I totally agree with you for the limit. I am always giving the next term on purpose. Have a look at  http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/8339/teaching-limits-and-asymptotics-at-the-same-time to see my concerns. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

If you already know how to [find the limit $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \dfrac{ \sqrt[3]{1+ x } - \sqrt[3]{1-x }}{x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527254/limit-in-form-of-0-0) and also that [$\dfrac{\sin x}x$ tends to 1](//math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1), then you can simply use
$$
\frac {\sqrt[3]{1+\sin x} - \sqrt[3]{1- \sin x}}{x} = 
\frac {\sqrt[3]{1+\sin x} - \sqrt[3]{1- \sin x}}{\sin x} \cdot \frac{\sin x}x.
$$

Comment: Ultimately when $x \to 0$ then $\sin x  ∼x$ and we can replace $\sin x$ with $x$ ?

Comment: That's true, but *only in some situations.* (Sometimes the terms of order $x^2, x^3, \dots$ are not negligible. Sometimes such replacement can change result completely.)

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim _{ x\to 0 }{ \frac { { (1+\sin  x) }^{ \frac { 1 }{ 3 }  }-{ (1-\sin  x) }^{ \frac { 1 }{ 3 }  } }{ x }  } \frac { \left( { (1+\sin  x) }^{ \frac { 2 }{ 3 }  }+{ (1+\sin  x) }^{ \frac { 1 }{ 3 }  }{ (1-\sin  x) }^{ \frac { 1 }{ 3 }  }+{ (1-\sin  x) }^{ \frac { 2 }{ 3 }  } \right)  }{ \left( { (1+\sin  x) }^{ \frac { 2 }{ 3 }  }+{ (1+\sin  x) }^{ \frac { 1 }{ 3 }  }{ (1-\sin  x) }^{ \frac { 1 }{ 3 }  }+{ (1-\sin  x) }^{ \frac { 2 }{ 3 }  } \right)  } =\\ =\lim _{ x\to 0 }{ \frac { 1+\sin { x-1+\sin { x }  }  }{ x } \frac { 1 }{ \left( { (1+\sin  x) }^{ \frac { 2 }{ 3 }  }+{ (1+\sin  x) }^{ \frac { 1 }{ 3 }  }{ (1-\sin  x) }^{ \frac { 1 }{ 3 }  }+{ (1-\sin  x) }^{ \frac { 2 }{ 3 }  } \right)  }  } =\\ =\lim _{ x\to 0 }{ \frac { 2\sin { x }  }{ x } \frac { 1 }{ \left( { (1+\sin  x) }^{ \frac { 2 }{ 3 }  }+{ (1+\sin  x) }^{ \frac { 1 }{ 3 }  }{ (1-\sin  x) }^{ \frac { 1 }{ 3 }  }+{ (1-\sin  x) }^{ \frac { 2 }{ 3 }  } \right)  }  } =\frac { 2 }{ 3 } \\ \\  $$

Comment: denominator + not -

Comment: Thanks , I accepted David answer because it was 2 minutes early, btw +1

Comment: yes,of course you are right